# Discord.js app keeps crashing on startup after uploaded new command

Tags: node.js, heroku, discord, discord.js

My Heroku discord bot keeps crashing on startup:

```js
2019-12-15T18:19:00.891355+00:00 app[web.1]: > node index.js
2019-12-15T18:19:00.891356+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2019-12-15T18:19:01.076509+00:00 app[web.1]: .-----------------------.
2019-12-15T18:19:01.076512+00:00 app[web.1]: | Command | Load Status |
2019-12-15T18:19:01.076513+00:00 app[web.1]: |---------|-------------|
2019-12-15T18:19:01.076514+00:00 app[web.1]: | help.js | ✅           |
2019-12-15T18:19:01.076515+00:00 app[web.1]: | ban.js  | ✅           |
2019-12-15T18:19:01.076516+00:00 app[web.1]: | kick.js | ✅           |
2019-12-15T18:19:01.076520+00:00 app[web.1]: '-----------------------'
2019-12-15T18:19:59.277750+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2019-12-15T18:19:59.186024+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2019-12-15T18:19:59.186024+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2019-12-15T18:19:59.262414+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 22
2019-12-15T18:19:59.202593+00:00 app[web.1]: Error waiting for process to terminate: No child processes
```

What is happening? It has only been doing it after I uploaded the kick.js file (shown below):

```js
const { getMember, formatDate, moderation } = require("../../functions.js");
const { RichEmbed } = require("discord.js");
const { stripIndents } = require("common-tags");

module.exports = {
  name: "kick",
  aliases: ["kk", "mod-2"],
  category: "moderation",
  description: "Kicks A Member",
  usage: "< ID or MENTION >",
  run: async (client, message, args) => {
    if (message.deletable)
      message
        .delete()
        .catch(err =>
          message.reply(
            "Error Deleting Message! Please Contact @Floofy Boi#7555"
          )
        );
    const user = message.mentions.users.first();

    message.channel
      .send(
        moderation("kick", "test", message.guild.member(user), message.author)
      )
      .delete(10000)
      .catch(err =>
        message.reply(
          `Error! Here Is The Error: \`\`\`${err}\`\`\`\n\nMake Sure To Notify @Floofy Boi#7555`
        )
      );
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you created your Procfile ?

if not create a file called `Procfile` in the main directory and 
add this in the file

`worker: node index.js`

considering the main file is index.js

if u still want to use web dyno then bind a port in the procfile

`web: node index.js -p $PORT` 
where`$PORT` is the port you want to bind

but i insist to use `worker` i am using that too almost 2 years for now XD